# Understanding and Solving Trigonometric Functions by Hand

Tags: functions, trigonometry, definition

I have heard of people who can do trigonometric functions by hand, without a calculator. I know that, for example, $\sin(\theta)=\text{opposite}/\text{hypotenuse}$, but calculators can also do $\sin(64.5)$, and I don't understand how that works. What really is a trigonometric function besides its ratio and how can you solve it by hand? I know that the ratio mentioned above can be used to create relationships between sides and angles, but what is the core definition of the function $\sin(x)$? I also know that if you graph $\sin(x)$, you get the wavy sinusoid but again, what is the function definition?

Comment: There are several ways to define sine. I presume the OPP over HYP that you mention was the first one, in ancient times. But I have understood that a digital calculator finds say $\sin 64.5$ via infinite series. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Series_definition)

Comment: More intuitively appears https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Unit_circle_definition

Comment: See this section on how Ptolemy computed chords: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_table_of_chords#How_Ptolemy_computed_chords

Comment: Also, "solve" is the wrong word. It seems to be one of those words that people use when they don't know the correct word. In this case you could say "compute" or "evaluate."

Answer (score 1):

Your questions

> What really is a trigonometric function besides its ratio and how can you solve it by hand?

are mostly answered somewhere in the Wikipedia article [Sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine). The trigonometric functions are very important functions in mathematics
and its applications. There are many different ways to interpret them some of which
are in the article. For example, the article states

> The chord function was discovered by Hipparchus of Nicaea (180–125 BCE) and Ptolemy of Roman Egypt (90–165 CE).

Essentially they produced brief tables of chords of circles of a suitable large size.
Later mathematicians expanded on such tables.

> Al-Khwārizmī (c. 780–850) produced tables of sines, cosines and tangents.

Thus, computing a trigonometric function involved looking in a suitable table with
perhaps linear interpolation between two
consecutive table entries. How the tables
themselves were produced by hand is another
matter. Over the past centuries
various efforts were made to publish tables
of trigonometric functions

> The Opus palatinum de triangulis of Georg Joachim Rheticus, a student of Copernicus, was probably the first in Europe to define trigonometric functions directly in terms of right triangles instead of circles, with tables for all six trigonometric functions; this work was finished by Rheticus' student Valentin Otho in 1596

These efforts culminated in the middle of the 20th century with the publication of the
*Handbook of Mathematical Functions* edited by Milton Abramowitz and Irene Stegun. The modern replacement for this is the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/)

> The new printed volume, the NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions, serves a similar function as the original A&S, though it is heavily updated and extended. The online version, the NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions (DLMF), presents the same technical information along with extensions and innovative interactive features consistent with the new medium.

The reality is that aside from the people
who computed the trigonometric tables, no
one computes them by hand because the tables
are available, and for a few decades now, calculators and computers are used to do it.
The Wikipedia article has a section "Software
implementations" which states

> Algorithms for calculating sine may be balanced for such constraints as speed, accuracy, portability, or range of input values accepted. This can lead to different results for different algorithms, especially for special circumstances such as very large inputs

and give a few details about such algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

There are many many many ways to approximate these things with high precision! The “core definition” of $\sin(x)$ is really just the circle construction. If you want an explicit formula to calculate it, one way to do this would be through a Taylor series, a calculus technique. What you’re thinking about are different *characterisations*, as we call them, of the same function $\sin$: and the circle one is one such characterisation.

The Taylor series is: $$\sin(x)=\sum_{n\text{ odd }}^\infty(-1)^{(n-1)/2}\frac{x^n}{n!}=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\cdots$$ from which one can compute sine to arbitrary precision. To be precise, that was a “Maclaurin series”. Other approximations and calculations exist of course - approximation theory and how computer scientists manage things is a very complex subject. Note that the $x$ in the above formula was in the angle measurement of *radians*.

The series I wrote is the Taylor series of sine centred at zero. When these series are centred at zero, they are called Maclaurin series. Consider sine of zero - it’s zero. Cosine of zero is one. The derivative of sine is cosine, and if you think about the other derivatives it’s periodic: sine-cosine-negative sine-negative cosine-sine. So the first second and third derivatives of sine at zero are $1,0,-1$ and you can do the rest. If you took the derivative of the series I wrote, all of those derivatives will equal the corresponding derivative of sine. For example, the third derivative of my series (at zero) is $-1$, (from the $x^3$ term) and notice how all the other terms disappear to zero at $x=0$! You’ll find it matches all the higher order derivatives of sine too.

Comment: Did you mean $(-1)^{(n-1)/2}$?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand much of that. Could you please simplify it for me. Thanks.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner good catch! I’ll fix that

Comment: @DragonflyRobotics from that I take it that you haven’t learnt much calculus. That’s fine! Trigonometry at lower levels of school really can only be understood visually, and the techniques of how to calculate it I’m afraid are locked behind the closed doors of calculus, Chebyshev polynomials, Padé approximants, Taylor series, the CORDIC algorithm... I think for you then the best answer is just: higher levels of maths allow us to analyse trigonometry better, such that our calculators can calculate! How computers compute anything is the modern marvel... and high level maths is behind lots of it

Comment: Geometrically there are ways you can do things: for example, the half and double angle identities can be proven with geometry - look them up! For example, if I know $\sin(60)=\sqrt{3}/2$, then I know $\sin(2\times60)=2\times(\sqrt{3}/2)\times\cos(60)=\sqrt{3}/2$ again. $\sin(60)=\sin(120)$ is also just cleanly seen from the graphs. Here I used degrees, since you used degrees in your question, but you must know that at higher levels we always use radians; all computer approximations will use radians I’m sure.

Comment: Also @DragonflyRobotics  you mentioned opposite over hypotenuse: someone in the comments pointed out the unit circle definition (what I called the circle definition). That is VERY important for all trigonometry - check out their link

Comment: I know a lot about basic calculus. I can integrate and derivate a lot of complex things and know a lot of the concepts of infinite series, infinity, and Fourier Transform. I just don't know what a Taylor series is. What I understood is that sin is just a construction of semicircles on an x-y plane.

Comment: Semicircles? @DragonflyRobotics  I’m not sure what that is. Think of the unit circle preferably. Anyway, no offence was intended. Even better if you know calculus! The Taylor series is, briefly, an infinite series that is equal to the original function at some starting point, and it is a polynomial that is exactly constructed to have the same derivative, second derivative, third derivative,... up to infinity as the original function, so that it changes in all the same ways and equals the original function everywhere. This only works for some functions, and the series won’t always converge

Comment: @DragonflyRobotics I edited my question to briefly talk about Taylor series. There’s a good 3 blue one brown YouTube video on them if you’re looking for a crash course on the subject